# How to call custom functions in view page using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I call my own functions in view file using Codeigniter?

I have a function:

function hoursToSeconds ($hour) { // $hour must be a string type: "HH:mm:ss"
    $parse = array();

```
if (!preg_match ('#^(?<hours>[\d]{2}):(?<mins>[\d]{2}):(?<secs>[\d]{2})$#',$hour,$parse)) {
     // Throw error, exception, etc
     throw new RuntimeException ("Hour Format not valid");
}

 return (int) $parse['hours'] * 3600 + (int) $parse['mins'] * 60 + (int) $parse['secs'];
```

}

I just called function like this `$sum += hoursToSeconds($rec['emp_late']);`, but it didn't work.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: whats your error ? what do you mean with : not work ?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with "but not work". Add the actual errormessage.

Comment: What file is the function above in? The view file? Where?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use helpers

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/helpers.html

A CodeIgniter helper is a PHP file with multiple functions.

Lets create helper say hour_helper.php in **application/helpers/**, paste your function

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('hoursToSeconds'))
{
   function hoursToSeconds ($hour) { // $hour must be a string type: "HH:mm:ss"
    $parse = array();

    if (!preg_match ('#^(?<hours>[\d]{2}):(?<mins>[\d]{2}):(?<secs>[\d]{2})$#',$hour,$parse)) {
         // Throw error, exception, etc
         throw new RuntimeException ("Hour Format not valid");
    }

     return (int) $parse['hours'] * 3600 + (int) $parse['mins'] * 60 + (int) $parse['secs'];
  }
}
```

**Load Helper**

This can be in your **controller**, **model** or **view** (not preferable)

```
// load helper 
$this->load->helper('hour_helper');

// to test 
echo hoursToSeconds('10:20:23');
```

If you want to share this helper across many module/controller/model then load automatically by adding it to the autoload configuration file i.e. `path/to/application/config/autoload.php`.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('hour_helper');
```

In your case load helper in your controller, and then call it in your view

Comment: its ok.foreach($datas as $rec)
    {
        //$count  ++;
        $emp_id =  $rec['id'];
        $emp_name =  $rec['emp_name'];
        $emp_in = $rec['emp_in'];
        $emp_status = $rec['emp_stat'];
        $emp_late = $rec['emp_late'];$sum += hoursToSecods($rec['emp_late']);  } $gm = gmdate("H.i", $sum);
    $leave_date=number_format($gm/5,1);
    $total_leave = $total_absent+$leave_date;
    $gm1 = gmdate("H.i", $sum1); 
    $extra_leave=number_format($gm1/5,1);          how to echo hoursToSeconds($rec['emp_late']); .i want get total sum of emp_late field values .for eg : 2.5

Answer (score 0):

check the argument given to `hoursToSeconds()` is in correct format **HH:mm:ss**

Comment: its correct. but i want database field values into the hoursToSeconds().

Comment: i try echo hoursToSeconds('20:10:30;); its working ..but table field values not get in to the hoursToSeconds('');

Comment: my table field(emp_late) values 00:01:00,10:01:02,01:20:30,10:22:30 .how to excute and return sum  hoursToSeconds() in that values.

Comment: `<?php
    
$sum = 0;
$times = ['00:01:00','10:01:02','01:20:30','10:22:30']; 

foreach($times as $time)
{
    $parse = array();
    if (!preg_match ('#^(?<hours>[\d]{2}):(?<mins>[\d]{2}):(?<secs>[\d]{2})$#',$time,$parse)) {
         // Throw error, exception, etc
         throw new RuntimeException ("Hour Format not valid");
    }
    $sum += (int) $parse['hours'] * 3600 + (int) $parse['mins'] * 60 + (int) $parse['secs'];

}

echo gmdate("H:i:s", $sum); 
?>`

 got the right answer 21:45:02 with your values, don't know why database values not working correctly